# xcode 7.3.1 can't connect to git

Tags: ios, xcode7, twitter-fabric

I am using Xcode 7.3.1. on Mac El Capitan. I have cloned a project from its repo in terminal but when I try to add a repository using Xcode - Preferences -> Accounts I get `authentication failed`. The same happens when I try Source Control -> Checkout.

I am following the instructions here: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/beta-walkthrough.html#add-udid

I have tried both gitosis@myserver:myproject.git and ssh://gitosis@myserver:myproject.git.

In terminal, `git clone gitosis@myserver:myproject.git` works fine.

I do have git-flow in this repo, could that upset xcode? I have tried just checking out master branch and using that with xcode but it didn't make any difference.

Another possible problem is that my git config file sets a port different to 22 and it may be that xcode does not pick this up from the config file and uses port 22 regardless?

Comment: If you can do this from the command line, you've no problem! Just do that. After you do, can you push from Xcode?

Comment: no, I can't get xcode to authenticate the connection to the git repo. Fabric seems to need the repo.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know fabric. My experience of SSH is that getting the private key into your SSH keychain is up to you, as described e.g. at github:  https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Comment: I'm very sure the keys are correctly placed in ~/.ssh and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys as appropriate. They are also listed in Keychain Access.

Comment: Well, I'm no help to you then. I don't know what fabric is. But it sounds like it's getting in the way somehow. If it's important to you to use fabric, maybe you should use the command-line, or (if it works in this situation) SourceTree. Personally, I _never_ use Xcode's built-in source control features; I just despise them. SourceTree, OTOH, rocks.

Comment: I am new to this but I imagine that Fabric is required to deploy to an actual remote device for testing. I know of no other way and have been just following the instructions linked above.

Comment: Right, but I'm just saying, let's distinguish what fabric does from what git does. I'm just trying to help get git working.

Comment: I'm not having any problems using git from the command line, just in Xcode.

Comment: Right, and I'm advising "so don't do that" and giving you some alternative approaches.

Comment: I believe I need to use Fabric and that it needs to be used from within the Xcode IDE.

Comment: If you say so. But that is far from obvious from the fabric documentation. It is about SSH, not Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this by entering the git connection string as ssh://myserver.com:2245/my-project.git.

Xcode apparently does not read my config file which was evident when it prompted me for the default certificate id_rsa instead of the one specified for the named server, together with the port specified in my ~/.ssh/git/config file.

I hope this helps somebody not to waste a couple of days as I did.